# Go sum type in json

Tags: json, go, parsing, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

## What I want to achieve

I'm parsing IAM Policies in Go. In IAM Policies, most of the fields can be either a string or an array of strings. It's hard to think these decision trees in my head what I want is kind of exhaustive pattern matching.

## What I did

I loeded a policy with `json.Unmarshal`

```golang
type Policy struct {
    Version    string      `json:"Version"`
    Id         string      `json:"ID,omitempty"`
    Statements []Statement `json:"Statement"`
}

type Statement struct {
    // ...
    Action        interface{}         `json:"Action"`              // string or array
    // ...
}
```

And iterating over statements.

```golang
switch ele := st.Action.(type) {
case string:
    action, _ := expandAction(ele, data)
    actions = append(actions, action...)
    setter(i, actions)
case []string:
    for _, a := range ele {
        if strings.Contains(a, "*") {
            exps, _ := expandAction(a, data)
            actions = append(actions, exps...)
        } else {
            actions = append(actions, a)
        }
        setter(i, actions)
        fmt.Println(actions)
    }
default:
    // interface{}
}
```

## The Problem

It always goes to the `default` case.

Can use reflection, but don't think I really should, since runtime could know types when `json.Unnarshal` is called.

Comment: It's worth including example JSON with questions like this ([minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). I'd expect a `[]interface{}` ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/GA26r8feEBw)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the [official document](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal)  the type for JSON array is **[]interface**. If you update []string to []interface then you can run the related case block. However, if you have to sure that is array of string, reflection can provide it.